# Jasmine unit-test case failing on the injection of the dependencies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

These are my controllers and services that I am trying to cover using Jasmine testing.

home.controller.js

```
var home = angular.module('home',[])

home.controller('home.controller', ['$scope','$location','homeService','localStorageService',function ($scope,$location,homeService,localStorageService) {
    homeService.directories(1001).then(function mySucces(_data) {
    $scope.dataHome = _data;
    }, function myError(response) {
         alert("error");
         
        });
     
     $scope.func = function(fileData) {
     localStorageService.set('fileId',fileData.id);
     console.log(fileData.id);
     $location.path("fileview");
        };
     
    }]);
```

home.service.js

```
var homeService = angular.module('homeService',[]); 

  homeService.factory('homeService',['$http', '$q', '$log','config', function ($http, $q, $log,config) {
    var serviceAPI = {};
    serviceAPI.directories = function (folderId) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(config.service + "/filevault-service/folders").then(function mySucces(response) {
    deferred.resolve(response.data.data);
        }, function myError(response) {
         deferred.resolve(response.status);
        });
    return deferred.promise;
    }

  
    return serviceAPI;

    }]);
```

Here goes my test case:

> ```
> describe('equality', function() {
>
>   var rootScope, homeService, scope, homeController, httpBackend, location, localStorageService;
>
> beforeEach(function(){
>
>   module('fileVaultApp');
>   
>   inject(function($controller, $httpBackend, $rootScope, $location, homeService, localStorageService){
>       rootScope = $rootScope;
>       scope = $rootScope.$new();
>       httpBackend = $httpBackend;
>       homeService = homeService;
>       location = $location;
>       localStorageService = localStorageService;
>       homeController = $controller('home.controller', { $scope: scope });
>       spyOn($location, 'path');
>   });
>   
> });
>
> console.log("hello");     
> it('check the home controller', function() {      
>       expect(1).toBe(1);      
>      });
> });
> ```

The thing is that when I am removing the "inject" snippet, the test runs good. As soon as it is injected, the problem arises.

The error has been given below:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) equality check the home controller FAILED
        C:/FileVault/file-vault/filevault-ui/static/scripts/lib-min.js:4641:53
        forEach@C:/FileVault/file-vault/filevault-ui/static/scripts/lib-min.js:321:24
        loadModules@C:/FileVault/file-vault/filevault-ui/static/scripts/lib-min.js:4601:12
        createInjector@C:/FileVault/file-vault/filevault-ui/static/scripts/lib-min.js:4523:30
        workFn@C:/FileVault/file-vault/filevault-ui/static/scripts/lib-min.js:50216:60
        inject@C:/FileVault/file-vault/filevault-ui/static/scripts/lib-min.js:50196:46
        C:/FileVault/file-vault/filevault-ui/tests/test_jasmine_spec.js:7:12
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.012 secs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject `_homeService_`, and `_localStorageService_`;

```
inject(function($controller, $httpBackend, $rootScope, $location, _homeService_, _localStorageService_){
```

Also you should inject all the dependencies of the controller when instantiating it.

```
describe('equality', function() {
    var rootScope, homeService, scope, homeController, httpBackend, location, localStorageService;
    beforeEach(function(){
      module('fileVaultApp');
      inject(function($controller, $httpBackend, $rootScope, $location, _homeService_, _localStorageService_){
         rootScope = $rootScope;
         scope = $rootScope.$new();
         httpBackend = $httpBackend;
         homeService = _homeService_;
         location = $location;
         localStorageService = _localStorageService_;
         homeController = $controller('home.controller', { $scope: scope, $location:location, homeService: homeService, localStorageService: localStorageService});
         spyOn($location, 'path');
     });
   });
   console.log("hello");
   it('check the home controller', function() {
       expect(1).toBe(1);
     });
});
```